# In docker compose file set environment as list

Tags: scala, docker, playframework, docker-compose

I have an application that on play that use aerospike

in application.conf i have a param that i can rewrite from environments

```
aerospike.hosts = ["192.168.33.10"]
aerospike.hosts = ${?DS_AEROSPIKE_HOSTS}
```

how i can set list of hosts in my docker compose file?

```
version: '3.1'

services:
     ds-aerospike-db:
        image: aerospike/aerospike-server
        restart: always
        volumes: 
          - volume:/opt/aerospike/etc
        command: ["--config-file","/opt/aerospike/etc/aerospike.conf"]
        ports:
          - 3000:3000
     dashboard:
        image: dashboard:0.1
        restart: always
        ports:
            - 9000:9000
        environment:
         DS_AEROSPIKE_HOSTS: '["192.168.33.10"]'
```

this format is an error DS_AEROSPIKE_HOSTS: '["192.168.33.10"]'

Answer (score 3):

I believe you can't pass an array to the ENV variable.
But you can pass it as a string, and then, later, parse string at your application.

```
environment:
  - DS_AEROSPIKE_HOSTS='192.168.33.10,192.168.33.11'
```

the valid docker-compose.yml syntax is stated at docs
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

I'm not familiar with scala, but I believe you can do something like

`aerospike.hosts = ${?DS_AEROSPIKE_HOSTS}.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options:

1. You can include a `docker.conf` file in your Docker build and inject the settings you want into that file. Then you can [include](https://github.com/lightbend/config/blob/master/HOCON.md#include-syntax) the `docker.conf` file from your `application.conf`. E.g. add this to your `application.conf`:

   ```
   include "docker.conf"
   ```
2. You can use an environment varible to pass a string value (as suggested by Stanislav) but then convert it to a sequence. The idiomatic way to do this is to make a [`ConfigLoader`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.6.7/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Configuration.scala#L1009) and then use it to convert a `String` to a `Seq[String]`. E.g. something like:

   ```
   implicit val stringSeqLoader: ConfigLoader[Seq[String]] =
     ConfigLoader(_.getString).map(_.split(','))
   ```